# How to use querySelectorAll on an detached dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  need to pass to the actionSorter() method and HTMLCollection, I am wondering how to do it creating a temporary div detached from the DOM.

Any ideas?

```
       var temp = document.createElement('div');
        temp.className = 'temp';
        temp.dataset.href = 'zoomout';
        var coll = document.querySelectorAll('.temp');
        this.actionSorter(coll);



actionSorter: function($el) {

            var href = $el[0].dataset.href;
            if (href === 'viewup') {
                Viewer.itemAnimateUp();
            }
            if (href === 'viewright') {
                Viewer.itemAnimateRight();
            }
            if (href === 'viewdown') {
                Viewer.itemAnimateDown()
            }
            if (href === 'viewleft') {
                Viewer.itemAnimateLeft();
            }
            return false;
        },
```

Comment: Why do you need to query? `temp` is already an element, can't you pass that?

Comment: What is an actionsorter?

Comment: try `this.actionSorter(temp);`

Comment: I have added the code to actionSorter as you can see it has $el[0] as it take the first item of an array alike object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do `querySelectorAll` because you have already the element.

Is sufficient pass the `temp` element

```
this.actionSorter(temp);
```

however, if your element is more complex and you want to find something inside a temporary element not attached to DOM, you can call `querySelectorAll` method of the element, like

```
temp.querySelectorAll(".selector")
```

Note that `querySelectorAll` returns an array of elements.

UPDATE: according with your code... simply you should pass an array as argument

```
  var temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.className = 'temp';
  temp.dataset.href = 'zoomout';
  this.actionSorter( [temp] ); // <--- note temp into array
```

Comment: I have posted the complete code for actionSorter, could you please tell me if your answer is still valid? thanks

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
   var temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.className = 'temp';
    temp.dataset.href = 'zoomout';
    this.actionSorter(temp);
```